If I was accused of not talking to customers, should I ignore it or defend?
I have a part time job where I get sent to different retail stores. In these stores I demo products or handout samples. I recently got a new manager. He said he received a complaint from a store that I had been on my phone most of the time and not engaging with customers, and that if this happens again he would be cancelling shifts. Honestly I spoke with every customer who came in the store. Should I bother to reply to the email or not? Obviously I don’t have a way to prove it.
In general when is it good to act defensive or just ignore it? What concerns me is the cancel confirmed shifts part. Should I ask how many strikes I get and how often they get reset?

So your manager says you were on your phone. You say you didn’t ignore customers, but at anytime other than approved break, were you on your phone?

TBH there were times I had no work to do and was on my phone for leisure. There were also times I was on my phone for work purposes. But if there were customers in the store, I was definitely interacting with them.

@JoeStrazzere I'm not sure and that's part of why I'm asking. Possibilities I can think of are 1) there is an element of truth and they want to add more padding to add impact 2) there was a miscommunication, for example they had the dates wrong and meant to write this about someone else 3) they had an issue with me for some sort of socially unacceptable reason (e.g. sexist) and don't want me back.

Don't ignore. Don't defend. Say "of course!" and make sure you are seen to be following that directive. Even if you were already doing so.

Ignoring feedback from your manager (especially negative feedback) is usually a Bad Idea, and is unlikely to make it go away.

He said he received a complaint from a store that I had been on my phone most of the time and not engaging with customers, and that if this happens again he would be cancelling shifts. Honestly I spoke with every customer who came in the store.

There are two parts to that feedback. You've said that you spoke to every customer (the store manager clearly disagrees - but we have no way of knowing which is true). However, you've not said anything about the comments that you were "on your phone most of the time".
In a lot of environments (especially retail), if a manager sees someone using their personal mobile phone during the day then they view that very negatively Because they see it that rather than doing the job that they're paying you to do, you're faffing around on Angry Birds/Facebook/TikTok/whatever, and think that if a customer comes in and sees the staff ignoring them because they're busy on their phones, that sends a really bad image. Some stores even go as far as making employees lock their phones away at the start of a shift so they can't use them at all on the shop floor.
So you should respond to your manager, challenge feedback where believe that it is untrue (but try not to come across as too defensive - especially since you're basically calling the store manager a liar), and accept it where it is true, and improve things going forward. Perhaps structured along the lines of:

I was using my mobile phone during quiet periods where there were no customers in the store.
When customers were present, I was engaging with them and doing X, Y and Z.
I'll make sure not to be using my phone in future on the shop floor.

A big part of that should be making sure that a store manager never sees you on your personal phone, unless you know that they're happy for staff to be using them on the shop floor, and there is literally nothing else productive that you can be doing. So when you go to a store, you should make sure that you're speaking to the manager, and understanding what their expectations of you are.

Looking at your post history, this isn't the first time you say that you've been false accused of things at work, and you've also made several posts about communication issues with (previous?) managers.
And maybe you're just unlucky and keep running into bad and dishonest managers (there are plenty of them out there). But you should also do some self-reflection, because at some point it becomes hard to ignore a pattern.

Just to clarify, my manager is not the same as the store manager. I technically don't work for the store. So in summary you are saying I should challenge the feedback?

"Looking at your post history..." given the two times it's happened over the years, I wouldn't call this a pattern.

@myusernameis123 I have never had a manager make blatantly false accusations against me, and it's happened at least twice to you in 15 months. And as I said in my post, maybe you're just unlucky; but that doesn't mean that you shouldn't reflect on this and try to understand why it's happening.

@myusernameis123 if it's your manager who emailed you, then you should reply to them. But you should also speak to both your manager and future store managers (when you arrive) to make sure that you're clear on what their expectations are of you.

If the OP needs to keep their phone with them for work purposes (e.g. to keep in touch with the line manager), consider leaving the shop floor to use it (e.g. go to the staff cafeteria, warehouse, different aisle, leave the store, whatever). At least if you're absent customers won't know you're supposed to be, there rather than them (or managers) seeing you on your phone and thinking you're ignoring your responsibilities. And keep a minimal record of the times you're absent and why (hopefully it's not too frequent) so you can cross-reference against any complaints of absenteeism.

@Gh0stFish I mean this in a serious way but I'm not sure what people mean by 'self reflection' in contexts like this. The fact that I made the post shows that I'm thinking about it.

@Gh0stFish not sure if it changes anything, but with this job I normally have very little interaction with the store manager. I really don't work for them or the store. They do not work for the company I work for. Now that I'm thinking of it, they might not no that some of the time I need to be on my phone for work purposes. I guess I will ask my manager about this.

@myusernameis123 reading your posts, they both give the impression that you acted impeccable and that these issues are 100% the fault of other people being dishonest liars and 0% because you or anything you did. Self-reflection is to ask yourself, in the cold light of day once your initial anger has gone away, whether that's really true.

Managers often take action on the "optics" of a situation, not the reality. This is an example of such. So, make sure that the "optics" are good. When on the floor, no phone.

Ask for a meeting with the complaining company person and your manager.
As it stands, you are playing the "whispering game" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers between managers. The only result is you lose.
Because any conversation that you are not included, you can't defend your self.
Be proactive. Tell them to review their store CCTV recordings. This assumes that you are being 100% accurate. If so, let the evidence show it.
If you needed to be on the phone while on the floor, be 100% in explaining why it was for company business. (If it was.)
If you have nothing to hide, you are good.

@JoeStrazzere - Heck yes. They likely won't, but the point is to pushback hard. Assuming OP is telling the truth, why should they accept the ding without fighing back hard? If they evidence exists - prove it. Normally I agree with your answers and comments. I am curious why you don't think OP should pushback?

Just laugh and deny it offhandedly and quietly watch the response. In my experience some/many managers are full of crap.
You can move forwards from that. Generally a good option when surprised with something negative is to pass it back as if it's a joke and gauge responses. This gives you time to get your head sorted, find out more information, and admits nothing.
A good manager would show you and discuss the complaint, not be vague about it.
